# Join 2 tables where one table may or may not have an entry

Tags: sql, join, postgresql-9.4

i have 2 tables (person + activities)

Person

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Axel |
| 3 | William |

Activities

| activity_id | person_id | activity_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Login |
| 2 | 1 | Visited Website |
| 3 | 1 | Logout |
| 4 | 3 | Login |
| 5 | 3 | Logout |

As you can see John and William have both several activities. But Axel has no activities at all.

The result i try to achieve is as follows.
I want to select id and name from every entry of the person table and the activity_id and activity_type from the activity table.

If the person has no activities yet, the id and name of the person should still be shown.
And if the person has more then one activity, only the one with the highest id should be shown.

**The result i aim for:**

| id | name | activity_id | activity_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3 | Logout |
| 2 | Axel | null | null |
| 3 | William | 5 | Logout |

When i try a left join:

```
select p.id, p.name, a.activity_id, a.activity_type
from person p left join activity a on p.id = a.person_id
order by p.id
```

i get this result:

| id | name | activity_id | activity_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | Login |
| 1 | John | 2 | Visited Website |
| 1 | John | 3 | Logout |
| 2 | Axel | null | null |
| 3 | William | 4 | Login |
| 3 | William | 5 | Logout |

But as i only one want one entry per person i added the following where-clause:

```
select p.id, p.name, a.activity_id, a.activity_type
from person p left join activity a on p.id = a.person_id
where a.id = (select max(id) from activity a2 where a2.person_id = p.id)
order by p.id
```

This is the result:

| id | name | activity_id | activity_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3 | Logout |
| 3 | William | 5 | Logout |

The entry for John and William are as i wanted. Only the 'last' activity is shown.
The problem is Axel is not shown anymore.

Any help appriciated.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Switch WHERE to AND.

Comment: By not taking into account NULL values your WHERE converted LEFT JOIN to INNER really.

Comment: @jarlh you did it :) many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres the simplest and fastest method is usually to use a Postgres extension to SQL, `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (p.id) p.id, p.name, a.activity_id, a.activity_type
from person p left join
     activity a
     on p.id = a.person_id
order by p.id, a.activity_id desc;
```

`distinct on` returns one row for keys specified in the parentheses.  The specific row is determining by the `order by`.

For performance, I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
select p.id, p.name, a.activity_id, a.activity_type
from person p left join
     (select distinct on (a.person_id) a.*
      from activity a
      order by a.person_id, a.activity_id desc
     ) a
     on p.id = a.person_id;
```

And then creating an index on `activity(person_id, activity_id desc)`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! But the execution time went from 700ms to 7sec. This here is a simplified SQL. My real statement is a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option you could use, which might be more performant with the correct indexes in place, to use a window function to identify the activity per person

```
select p.id, p.name, a.activity_id, a.activity_type
from person p 
left join (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by person_id order by activity_id desc) rn
    from activities
)a on a.person_id=p.id and a.rn=1
```